# Get details from a LINQ query from Controller to Razor View

Tags: c#, linq

Currently trying to build a bulletin in my application where the logged in user simply types in something in a text box and the results are then displayed with a list of other bulletins.

My problem is that I don't want to display the dropdown box of names, I just want the admins' ID who is logged in to post. FYI, I messed up my admin in this app, their ID is different to their userID but their usernames are the same and that is how I get their ID.

I want to store the result of a linq query in the HiddenFor in my razor page. I've been trying with ViewBags but I just get **cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'system.collections.ienumerable'**

Here is my Create part of my controller:

```
    // GET: Bulletins/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        string username = Membership.GetUser().UserName;

        var getAdmin = (from a in db.Admins
                        where username == a.AdminUsername
                        select a.AdministrationId).SingleOrDefault();


        ViewBag.AdministrationId = new SelectList(db.Admins, "AdministrationId", "AdministratorName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Bulletins/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BulletinsID,DetailsOfBulletin,AdministrationId")] Bulletins bulletins)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string username = Membership.GetUser().UserName;

            var getAdmin = (from a in db.Admins
                            where username == a.AdminUsername
                            select a.AdministrationId).SingleOrDefault();

            db.Bulletins.Add(bulletins);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AdministrationId = new SelectList(db.Admins, "AdministrationId", "AdministratorName", bulletins.AdministrationId);
        return View(bulletins);
    }
```

And my Razor View:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AdministrationId)
```

Honestly couldn't find anything so any help would be appreciated. x

Answer (score 0):

First, you should materialize your query to get all admin object from your db:

```
var adminIds = db.admins.Select(a => a.Id).ToList();
ViewBag.AdministrationIds = adminIds;
```

Then, if you are using ViewBag to access those admin ids in the view, you will need to foreach over them and render a hidden input with the ID as the value:

```
@{
    foreach (var item in ViewBag.AdministrationIds)
    {
        <input type ="hidden" value="@item" />
    }
}
```